# cokernel of a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

I am dealing with the following problem:

Given $f:R \rightarrow R^2$ such that $f(x)=(x,-x)$ I am trying to compute the quotient group of $f$.

So I know that this is the group $R^2/Im(f)$.

I find that $Im(f)=\{(x,y)\in R^2 / y=-x\}$

Then, I dont know how to continue...

If i am applying the definition correctly, it should be the set $\{z+x,u-x\}$ for $(z,u) \in R^2$  but I dont think that this is the proper result. Any advice for this?

Moreover, I am attending lectures for Algebraic Topology and I realize that I am weak in Algebra (I did the very basics of group theory as an undergaduate student). Would you suggest me to study simultaneously group theory in order to keep up with the Alg. Topology?

Comment: You want to see $R^2/Im(f)$ as isomorphic to a particular group? You can check for instance that $R^2/Im(f)\simeq R^2/\langle (x,y)-(y,x)\rangle_{(x,y)}$, namely the quotient $R^2/Im(f)$ satisfies $(x,y)\equiv (y,x)$ for each pair $(x,y)\in R^2$.

Comment: Yes sorry for not describing explicitly. I want to find the isomorphism classes of this group.

Comment: do you mean the cosets? for the isomorphism classes you would need more information on the group $R$ i believe.

Comment: the cosets are the sets $(x,y)+Im(f)$ for $(x,y)\in R^2$, so these are the sets $[(x,y)]=\{(x+z,y-z): z \in R\}$. You were correct.

Comment: By R I mean the real numbers, sorry for not declaring it.

Comment: Berci's answer shows it actually holds for any abelian group

Answer (score 1):

We can assume $R$ is any Abelian group here.

Consider the homomorphism $g:R^2\to R,\ g(x,y)=x+y$.
Its kernel is just ${\rm im}(f)$ and it's surjective, as $g(x,0)=x$ for any $x\in R$, hence by the *first isomorphism theorem*,
$$R^2/{\rm im}(f)\,\cong\,R\,.$$

Alternatively, one can directly show that $R$ with map $g$ satisfies the universal property of cokernel: $g\circ f=0$ and  any group homomorphism $h:R^2\to S$ with $h\circ f=0$ uniquely factors through $g$.

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution with the F.I.T. was very clear. First of all, sorry for not declaring that by R i mean the real numbers ( Im not so used to Latex yet), so you correctly assumed that we talk about an Abelian group. I guess that picking this specific g is not intuitive right? I mean, at that kind of problems, I should think about a map that its domain is the range of f and its kernel is the image of f and then use the F.I.T..

Comment: Yes, that's correct, though in this specific example the choice of $g$ was rather intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers so far.
In order to not spam with new posts, I would like to give my solution to a similar problem and I would like your feedback about it if that is possible.

I want to find the isomorphism classes of the quotient group of the homomorphism
$f:\mathbb{Z} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}$, with $f(n,m)=(2n,2m)$.

I compute that $Im(f)=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}/x=2k, k \in \mathbb{Z} , y \in \{\bar{0}_{4},\bar{2}_{4}\}\}$.

So in order to compute the $\mathbb{Z} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}/Im(f)$ I have to compute the
$aIm(f)=\{a+h:h\in Im(f)\}$ for every $a\in \mathbb{Z} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}$.

Now $a$ can be $(z,\bar{0}_{4}),(z,\bar{1}_{4}),(z,\bar{2}_{4}),(z,\bar{3}_{4})$ where $z\in \mathbb{Z}$

Doing the computation, I find that the quotient group is $\{(\mathbb{Z},\{\bar{0}_{4},\bar{2}_{4}\}),(\mathbb{Z},\{\bar{1}_{4},\bar{3}_{4}\})\}$

But considering the set $\{\bar{0}_{4},\bar{2}_{4}\}$ I observe that this is the $\bar{0}_{2}$ and that $\{\bar{1}_{4},\bar{3}_{4}\}$ is the $\bar{0}_{4}$. Now noticing that every element of $\bar{0}_{4}$ is into $\bar{0}_{2}$, I find that the group  $\mathbb{Z} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}/Im(f)$ is $\mathbb{Z} \bigoplus \{\bar{0}_{2}\}$

Is the solution correct?

One remark. Considering that the cokernel of a function shows the "divergence" of a map of being surjective, I could consider that the result is correct because: $f$ "cuts" the odd integers (thats why $\mathbb{Z}$) and also "cuts" the elements $(2,6,10,14,...)$ and these elements belong in $\bar{0}_{2}$. Does this way of thinking make sense?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look for the cokernel here as well, then it's not correct, it seems you quotient out by the kernel of $f$ or something.. The result should be $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$. Can you find the cokernel quotient map?

Answer (score 0):

I want to find the isomorphism classes of the cokernel of $f$. I think i divided by the image, but maybe I did something wrong during the further computations.

EDIT: Actually I think that I have found my mistake. So, I have that $Im(f)=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}/x=2k, k \in \mathbb{Z} , y \in \{\bar{0}_{4},\bar{2}_{4}\}\}$ and when I divide $\mathbb{Z} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{4}$ by $Im(f)$ I obtain for the first part $\mathbb{Z}/2k$ (which is $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$) and for the second part the $\{\bar{0}_{4},\bar{2}_{4}\}$ (which is $\bar{0}_{2}$) and $\{\bar{1}_{4},\bar{3}_{4}\}$ (which is $\bar{1}_{2}$) so the second part is again $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$. So the cokernel of $f$ is indeed $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

I hope that now it is ok. Thank you very much for your help, things start getting clear about that now.

Comment: Yes, better. This other question (implicitly put as answers) should have gone as another post, nevertheless.